# Can Apache Access Logs be kept separated & also combined as well too?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, access-log

My question my be a bit confusing, and sorry for that. Here is what i need:

Well, i have (let's say) 3 Websites hosted on one Apache (which are defined inside each `VirtualHost` settings. Then i **currently** log their Access Logs separately as in:

- /var/log/httpd/website-a.com.access_log
- /var/log/httpd/website-b.com.access_log
- /var/log/httpd/website-c.com.access_log

Define something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website-a.com
    ..
    CustomLog logs/website-a.com.access_log common
    ..
</VirtualHost>
```

So it is all fine. But **at the same time**, i ALSO want them (all the access logs) altogether inside the Apache's default localhost log file *(i'm not sure how to call that one)*. May be:

- /var/log/httpd/access_log *(I think this is default one)*

---

In other words, is there a way to (how to) keep the Access Logs in the separated manner, and at the same time, keep all in the same combined file also?

---

So this will allow me to see each of the Access Logs in their separated files. And at the same time, i can see all the logs in one place also IF I NEED TO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website-a.com
    ..
    CustomLog logs/website-a.com.access_log common
    CustomLog logs/access_log common
    ..
</VirtualHost>
```

Just add `CustomLog logs/access_log common` to each virtual host as a second log file and apache will write to both.